# NODE.js unable to use restful data obtained by restler

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, rest, restler

I am using restler with NODE.JS to obtain data from a live feed. If I want to just display the whole feed to the screen it works beautifully, however I want to actually grab the feed and filter it down and only issue what is needed.

Here is the snippet of code from my API that works

```
app.get('/cis/public/:crs', function (req, res) {

    fullpath = 'http://(domain)/timetables/search_crs.php?crs='+req.params.crs;

    rest.get(fullpath).on('complete', function(result) {
        if (result instanceof Error) {
            console.log('Error:', result.message);
            this.retry(1000); // try again after 1 sec
        } else {
            res.send(result);
        }
    });

});
```

This displays the full feed on screen, though not formatted as I would expect.

This is an example of what I want to do, and this works fine if I am working with local JSON files.. example if I typed in something like

**var results = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./data/ppm.json', 'utf8'));**

However when using restful in the following format I get a failure

```
app.get('/cis/public/:crs', function (req, res) {

    fullpath = 'http://(domain)/timetables/search_crs.php?crs='+req.params.crs;

    rest.get(fullpath).on('complete', function(result) {
        if (result instanceof Error) {
            console.log('Error:', result.message);
            this.retry(1000); // try again after 1 sec
        } else {
            var National = result.GetStationBoardResult.locationName;
            res.send(National);
        }
    });

});
```

The error that is thrown is

```
            var National = result.GetStationBoardResult.locationName;
                                                       ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'locationName' of undefined
```

How can I use the data obtained from restler within node and not just for display on the screen.

Here is a sample (top part) of the returned JSON

```
{
  "GetStationBoardResult": {
    "generatedAt": "2015-03-18T10:49:36.9120348+00:00",
    "locationName": "Swindon",
    "crs": "SWI",
    "platformAvailable": true,
    "trainServices": {
```

Thanks

EDIT : Here is the final piece of code that now gives me useful and USABLE JSON to work with.

```
app.get('/cis/public/:crs/:total', function (req, res) {

    fullpath = 'http://(domain)/timetables/search_crs.php?crs='+req.params.crs+'&total='+req.params.total;

    rest.get(fullpath).on('complete', function(result) {
        if (result instanceof Error) {
            console.log('Error:', result.message);
            this.retry(1000); // try again after 1 sec
        } else {
            var Results = JSON.parse(result);
            res.send(Results);
        }
    });

});
```

I can now do extra things with Results. and break down the JSON into more usable (and filtered) info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens when you console.log

```
result
```

Based on the error your object result does not have a property called

```
GetStationBoardResult
```

Edit: as the result was a string and not an object, it will be solved using:

```
var National = JSON.parse(result).GetStationBoardResult.locationName;
```

Comment: Added snippet of returned JSON to question (ay bottom)

Comment: Given that you are trying to access a property of variable in javascript object notation, it should work just fine. Are you certain that the returned 'result' is an object, not a string?

Comment: THAT is exactly what I was thinking judging by how it is laid out, but in the examples of restler I cant find anyway of returning output any other way. Also when I feed the results into an online JSON viewer, it certainly renders ok. Maybe I need to covert to JSON just in case, but tyhat keeps adding loads of "/" which corrupt the JSON

Comment: Have you tried `var National = JSON.parse(result).GetStationBoardResult.locationName;`

Comment: ok excellent, that returned the correct result, but as a string whereas it is important to retain the JSON aspect. Essentially I am taking a large chunk or JSON and want to render it down into something more manageable.

Comment: However I suppose I COULD work with that to be honest, I just have to start constructing a new JSON array from the data

Comment: OK Got it based on your answer. Good job! Many thanks!